# pi compute dual camera capture

Tags: python, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi

I've got a Raspberry pi compute module setup with two PiNoIR camera modules.

I'm trying to capture 2 video streams to be used on a raspberry pi 3 at a later date. Here is the configuration:

- Frame rate = 30
- resolution = 640x480
- language = Python (with picamera)
- chosen libraries = Opencv 3.1.0

The idea originally was to use the hardware device (e.g. /dev/videoX), but the bcm2835_v4l2 kernel module currently only supports 1 camera, and I'm not experienced with developing kernel modules do try and get it to support 2 cameras.

I've tried using the test code from the [picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#recording-video-to-a-file) docs, but this only works for a single camera. I know that defining `PiCamera(0)` or `PiCamera(1)` will select either camera, however I do not know how to get it to record two streams together.

I've tried the below, and I've tried using [this guide](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/) for working with python and opencv. The guide is only focused around one camera, and I need both working.

```
!/usr/bin/python
import picamera
import time

cameraOne = picamera.PiCamera(0)
cameraTwo = picamera.PiCamera(1)

cameraOne.resolution = (640,480)
cameraTwo.resolution = (640,480)

cameraOne.framerate = 30
cameraOne.framerate = 30

cameraOne.start_recording('CameraOne.mjpg')
cameraTwo.start_recording('CameraTwo.mjpg')

counter = 0

while 1:
        cameraOne.wait_recording(0.1)
        cameraTwo.wait_recording(0.1)

        counter += 1

        if counter == 30:
                break

cameraOne.stop_recording()
cameraTwo.stop_recording()
```

The code snippet above generates two 10 second videos with a single frame from each camera

I'm not sure where to go from here, as I'm not well versed in Python, and I'm more experienced in C++, hence the want for hardware device control (e.g. /dev/videoX).

All I require is the ability to record the streams of both cameras simultaneously to be used in processing stereo vision.

I am seeking either a pure python-picamera solution, or an opencv integrated solution.

Comment: I also faced the same problem, you have to options or use the 'stereo_mode' and 'stereo_decimate' parameters in the PiCamera class or you transform your code to two separate threads (if you don't you will receive non balanced number of frames to your videos).